# How to query DynamoDB based on Partition Key and Sort Key [Java]?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to DynamoDB and wanted to know how can we query on a table in DynamoDB with the hashKey and sortKey.

I have a table named `Items`. It`s schema is

```
1. Product (Partition Key of type String)
2. ID (Sort Key of type int)
3. Date ( attribute of type String)
```

My query for getting all items having `product = 10` is

```
Items it = new Items();
it.setProduct("apple");

DynamoDBQueryExpression<Items> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Items>()
            .withHashKeyValues(it);


List<Items> itemList = mapper.query(Items.class, queryExpression);
```

But, now I want to get all items having `Product = "apple"` and `ID = 100`.

I can I write a query in `Java` for `DynamoDB` .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to get the data from DynamoDB using partition key and sort key. You can use the `load` method present on `DynamoDBMapper` class.

```
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient);
String product = "ball";
Integer id = 1;
Item itemObj = mapper.load(Items.class, product, id);
```

**Model class i.e. in your case Item class:-**

You should have the Item class defined with proper annotation for Hash and Range key.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Items")
public class Item {

    private String product;
    private Integer id;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "Product")
    public String getProduct() {
        return autoID;
    }   
    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "ID")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }           
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying,  table; no mapping for RANGE key

Comment: ID is the sort key not range key.

Comment: Updated the answer with model class. Similarly, you can define the non-key attributes as well. But for load to work, the non-key attributes are not required. Sort key is otherwise called range key

Comment: Is load as fast as query, if I wanted to run this on a very large database.

Comment: There is no performance. The only difference is you can't filter by non key attributes. Query API has a facility to include non-key attributes on filter criteria along with key attributes.

Comment: How would I write a query to get output similar to SELECT * FROM item WHERE id IN (10,20,30).

Answer (score 6):

I would like to add a more low-level way (not using Mapper and annotations):

```
String accessKey = ...; // Don't hardcode keys in production.
String secretKey = ...; 

AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDBClient =
      = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withRegion("us-east-1")
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)))
            .build();

String tableName = ...
Map.Entry<String, AttributeValue> partitionKey = ...
Map.Entry<String, AttributeValue> sortKey = ...

GetItemRequest request = 
    new GetItemRequest().withTableName(tableName)
                        .withKey(partitionKey, sortKey);

GetItemResult result = dynamoDBClient.getItem(request);
Map<String, AttributeValue> item = result.getItem();
```

Answer (score 2):

Given this DynamoDB table:

[image]

The table has the following details:

- Partition key — Artist
- Sort key — SongTitle

Given this class:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="Music")
public class MusicItems {

    //Set up Data Members that correspond to items in the Music Table
    private String artist;
    private String songTitle;
    private String albumTitle;
    private int awards;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="Artist")
    public String getArtist() { return this.artist; }
    public void setArtist(String artist) {this.artist = artist; }

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName="SongTitle")
    public String getSongTitle() { return this.songTitle; }
    public void setSongTitle(String title) {this.songTitle = title; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="AlbumTitle")
    public String getAlbumTitle() { return this.albumTitle; }
    public void setAlbumTitle(String title) {this.albumTitle = title; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="Awards")
    public int getAwards() { return this.awards; }
    public void setAwards(int awards) {this.awards = awards; }



}
```

This code works:

```
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAttribute;
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBHashKey;
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper;
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperConfig;
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTable;

    public class UseDynamoMapping {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

       AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();
       MusicItems items = new MusicItems();

       try{

          //add new content to the Music Table
           items.setArtist("Famous Band");
           items.setSongTitle("Our Famous Song");
           items.setAlbumTitle("Our First Album");
           items.setAwards(0);

           // Save the item
           DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);
           mapper.save(items);

            //Load an item based on the Partition Key and Sort Key
           //both values need to be passed to the mapper.load method
           String artist = "Famous Band";
           String songQueryTitle = "Our Famous Song";

           // Retrieve the item.
           MusicItems itemRetrieved = mapper.load(MusicItems.class, artist, songQueryTitle);
           System.out.println("Item retrieved:");
           System.out.println(itemRetrieved);

            //Modify the Award value
           itemRetrieved.setAwards(2);
           mapper.save(itemRetrieved);
           System.out.println("Item updated:");
           System.out.println(itemRetrieved);


            System.out.print("Done");
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           e.getStackTrace();
       }

    }
}
```

URL to example - https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/java/example_code/dynamodb/src/main/java/aws/example/dynamodb/UseDynamoMapping.java

Answer (score 1):

```
GetItemRequest getItemRequest = new GetItemRequest().withTableName("Employee").
            addKeyEntry("departmentId", new AttributeValue().withS(String.valueOf(departmentId))).
            addKeyEntry("employeeId", new AttributeValue().withN(String.valueOf(employeeId)));

    Map<String, AttributeValue> responseItem = dynamoDbClient.getItem(getItemRequest).getItem();
```